# Can any potatoes be cooked in the microwave?

Tags: potatoes, microwave

I bought these baby potatoes from sainsburys and it says on the packet you can microwave them in 7.5 minutes and they will be ok to cook.  I imagine they are not precooked or am I wrong?

This got me thinking if I get any potatoes and cut them into small enough pieces can I heat them in the microwave without oil and butter same as with these baby potatoes?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: https://www.littlepotatoes.com/blog/microwave-101-how-to-cook-potatoes-in-the-microwave/

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can cook potatoes in a microwave. If you have not cut them up, poke a few holes in the side with a fork or knife point to allow steam to escape.

Comment: Don't cut potatoes up to cook them in the microwave, you need the jacket to keep the steam in, if you cut them up before microwaving they get very hard. Just poke them with a fork.

Comment: You can certainly put cut potatoes in a container, and cover with plastic, a plate, or a glass lid.